# How do I obtain the result summary from within a form on the view page?

Tags: views, 8, forms

I have a design requirement or ask that wants to have a search form at the top of a Views page look like the attached image.

[image]

So there is an exposed full text input, exposed sort by filters.

However, the result summary for the view would appear to need to go in the middle of the form.

Since this is on a View page, is there a way to get the current View and fetch its result summary within a `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: While slightly off-tangent, could https://www.drupal.org/node/2761273 point you in the right direction?

Comment: That looks interesting - is that 8.4.x only? I am on 8.2.6.

Comment: The issue is for Drupal 8.4.x just because those changes are applied first to the branch that is the development snapshot, and then to the other ones.

Answer (score -1):

> However, the result summary for the view would appear to need to go in
>   the middle of the form.
>
> Since this is on a View page, is there a way to get the current View
>   and fetch its result summary within a `hook_form_alter()`?

Don't complicate your Drupal life, and just [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

I assume you already added the Result Summary to your View's header. So just:

**style.css**

```
.view-id-[your-id] .view-header {

  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;

}
```